# impersonation problem

Tags: asp.net, impersonation

i am trying to implement impersonation in a project. this is the first time i am trying it
this is what i have done.

```
 <identity impersonate="true" userName="NS1\name" password="secret" />
```

i am using the username and password provided as the plesk credantials.

I don't know if my username format is correct.

These are the details.

**Windows 2003 shared server**

IIS6

provider name : space2host

thanks in advance

**Update:**this is the error i get

```
Could not create Windows user token from the credentials specified in the config file. Error from the operating system 'Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
```

Comment: You need to ask the question to have an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is "Plesk credentials"? Are they the ones used to log in to Plesk? If yes, I think they do not necessary correspond to the account on the machine with the web server.

Comment: yes.by plesk credentials i mean the user name and password i use to login to the plesk. If i cannot use this to impersonate  can you pls explain what you mean by -"account on the machine woth the web server".

Comment: Why do you think you are allowed to do impersonation on your hosting?You can only impersonate valid accounts and you don't necessarily have one on the web server machine.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. This is the answer I posted here : [Error with windows impersonation code in webconfig file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339422/error-with-windows-impersonation-code-in-webconfig-file)

I'm running Windows 8.1 and IIS 7 and I had the same message as the author.

These are the steps I followed to solve the issue :

**1) If not already set in Windows, set the password for the account to make it match with the information there is in the web.config file**

Go to PC settings -> Accounts -> Sign In option and set your password

**2) Add Windows authentication in IIS Windows feature**

a) Right click on the Windows logo in the bottom left corner

b) Click 'Control panel'

c) Click 'Programs'

d) Click 'Turn Windows features on or off'

e) Under 'Internet Information Services' -> 'World Wide Web Services' -> 'Security', check 'Windows Authentication'

**3) Restart the computer**

**4) In IIS Manager, in the 'IIS' group, click on 'Authentication'**

**5) Make sure the status of 'ASP.Net Impersonation' and 'Windows Authentication' are Enabled**

**6) Restart the computer and re-run the solution**

Also make sure that your web.config impersonate line contains the Domain like this :

*`<identity impersonate="true" userName="Domain\user" password="password" />`*

Answer (score 0):

face the similar issue yesterday, what you need to do is to ensure the user account you want to impersonate already exist in your debugging machine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to your question is in the error message: the account you are using does not exist or you supplied an incorrect password.

The question being *where* the user does not exist. If you are using `<authentication mode="Windows"/>` in Web.config (which I guess you are) it would mean that your Active Directory (the domain controller for your domain (`NS1`)) or your Windows-box (if `NS1` is the name of your (devel or server) machine) does not know the user. Actually I am unsure how (if?) impersonation works with something else than AD/Windows.

Btw: your format is correct. UserName like `<domain>\<username>` and a (valid) password in "password".

More information can as often be found on the [Microsoft website](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B306158&x=16&y=13).

Answer (score 0):

Adding the "complained" user to the IIS will solve the problem
Control Panel --> System and Security --> Administrative Tools --> (double click) Computer Management --> (expanse on left side column) Local Users and Groups --> (select) Users --> (right click right side panel and select) New User (remember to choose "Password never expired")